# How to fix Laravel bulk inserting records only saving first record to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to save multiple records to database. I think there must be something wrong with submitting array from front-end view.

Firstly, my  rows are dynamically generated with jquery.
I have tried var_dumping the request and it only gave me only first row. I added [] to the name in each input field name.

Some of Input fields in my View

```
    <td width="15%">
        <select class="form-control select2 item_id" name="item_id[]" required>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
        <select class="form-control select2 location_id" name="location_id[]"  required>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
        <input type="text" class="form-control package" name="package[]" required>
    </td>
```

Controller

```
$receive = new Receive();
    $receive->datetime = $request->datetime;
    $receive->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $receive->truck_id = $request->truck_id;
    $receive->from = $request->from;
    $receive->condition = $request->condition;
    $receive->space = $request->space;
    dd($request->all());
    if($receive->save()) {
        $id = $receive->id;
        foreach($request->item_id as $key=>$it) {
            $data = array('receive_id'=>$id,
                          'item_id'=>$request->item_id [$key],
                          'location_id'=>$request->location_id [$key],
                          'package'=>$request->package [$key],
                          'quantity'=>$request->quantity [$key],
                          'note'=>$request->note [$key],
                           );
            ItemReceive::create($data);
        }
        return back()->with('success', 'Received Items successfully');
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Received successfully.');
```

I except to save the array data into the database but only first row is coming to the backend.

Comment: The important part here is the data being sent via http. Use your browser's console to see what you're sending and then assert what goes wrong. Apparently, you're not sending arrays.

Comment: @Mjh If he wasn't sending an array, he wouldn't be able to use the `foreach` loop. I'd suggest doing `dd($request->all());` to see exactly what the controller is receiving.

Comment: @ChinLeung we don't know what he's sending, nor if he gets any warnings. It's all guessing at this point, seeing there's literally no info on the data being sent.

Comment: @Mjh Well he mentioned that the first record is saved properly in the database, therefore he must be receiving some data. Since the controller is looping in `$request->item_id`, so that must be an array...

Comment: @Mjh I tried dd(). Yes they are posting as arrays, But in array I can see that only one row is passing. Like this : 'item_id'=>array:1[0]=>"4"

Comment: The data is passed as an array but contains only first row. I think there must be something wrong in front view. I am saving to two tables which are related one to many. I am submitting all data in one form.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't prefer to insert single entry in DB, however, I would prefer to create an array and pass that array to insert as shown below:

try replacing your code with the following:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//you could also try
//$now = Carbon::now();
$arr = [];
foreach($request->item_id as $key=>$it) {
    $arr[] = array('receive_id'=>$id,
                  'item_id'=>$request->item_id[$key],
                  'location_id'=>$request->location_id[$key],
                  'package'=>$request->package[$key],
                  'quantity'=>$request->quantity[$key],
                  'note'=>$request->note[$key],
                  'created_at' => $now,
                  'updated_at' => $now
                );

}

ItemReceive::create($arr);

//make sure you have assigned a correct key in `$fillable` array in your `ItemReceive` model.
```

*Edit: 1*

Try adding `multiple` to select:

```
<select multiple name="bdhdh">
    <option>hdjdjd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you bulk-insert like that, opposed to inserting records one by one, wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: Can you please paste your full controller?

Comment: @dexter Yes. I have updated the question details. Thanks in advance,